# When someone sends me a erc721, does my wallet actually receiving it?

Tags: erc-20, nft, erc-721

Like erc20, when someone sends me a erc20 token, they're not actually sending the tokens to my address. Instead, they're sending a transaction to the Ethereum network that calls the transfer function of the ERC-20 contract with your address as the recipient and the amount of tokens to transfer.

The ERC-20 contract then updates its mapping of token balances, which records the number of tokens held by each address. This means that the balance of ERC-20 tokens associated with my address increases accordingly.

Does the same happen in the case of erc721?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the same happens with the ERC721, you simply become the owner of that NFT in the contract.

As you can see in the contract below from OpenZeppelin, the `transferFrom()` function calls `_transfer()`. This function, after the checking requirements does the following:

1. deletes token approval for the previous holder.
2. adds +1 to your balance of tokens in the `balances` mapping, and -1 to the previous holder.
3. updates the `_owners` mapping. All holders are simply mappings of the _owners.

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol

Comment: So how to find out a particular user owns how many nfts? Do I have to query the whole blockchain transactions and search the transactions for the particular address then separate the erc721 transactions, etcc?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to query the blockchain and check how many NFTs have been minted and are held by each wallet. You can of course, also make a custom mapping or use an extension if you're coding your own. `adds enumerability of all the token ids in the contract as well as all token ids owned by each account.`

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol